# How to get if Hour A is between Hour B and Hour C?

Tags: javascript

I tried this but it doesn't work because of the 24 hours cycles:

```
const isBetweenHours = (currentHour, startHour, endHour) => {
  if (currentHour >= startHour && currentHour <= endHour) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

example that works:

```
currentHour = 7 // 7AM
startHour = 10 // 10AM
endHour = 18 // 6PM
isBetweenHours(currentHour, startHour, endHour)
```

example that fails:

```
currentHour = 22 // 10PM
startHour = 21 // 9PM
endHour = 4 // APM
isBetweenHours(currentHour, startHour, endHour)
```

Comment: You need to add ALL the relevant code so we can reproduce your issue? What are the values for `currentHour`, `startHour`, and `endHour`? Where do these values come from?

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to compare like 3am to 3pm? Why not just convert to 24 hour cycle so that. 2am is 2 and 2pm is 14? Or if youre having an issue across days use unix epoch time and boom, problem solved completely.

Comment: How do you specify the hour? Are you using a 24 hour clock or AM and PM?

Comment: sorry about that, I edited it

Comment: [Your code is correct](https://repl.it/@codeguru/HeftyThisPaint). I think you need a different example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: With your edits, this should work? I'm not sure we understand what the problem is. Are you saying you want to go across days? Because then you obviously need a day variable.

Comment: With your new example, see Jon Hanlon's answer below

Comment: You can also convert the dates into a Unix timestamp and then compare.

`dateObject.getTime() / 1000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the end hour is less than the start hour then we are in the next day, so add 24 to get a true picture:

```
const isBetweenHours = (currentHour, startHour, endHour) => {
  if (endHour < startHour) { endHour += 24; }
  if (currentHour >= startHour && currentHour <= endHour) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as it should:

```js
const isBetweenHours = (currentHour, startHour, endHour) => {
  if (currentHour >= startHour && currentHour <= endHour) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

// example
currentHour = 7 // 7AM
startHour = 10 // 10AM
endHour = 18 // 6PM
console.log(isBetweenHours(currentHour, startHour, endHour)); // false: 7 is not between 10 and 18

currentHour = 13 // 1PM
startHour = 10 // 10AM
endHour = 18 // 6PM
console.log(isBetweenHours(currentHour, startHour, endHour)); // true: 13 is  between 10 and 18

currentHour = 18 // 6PM
startHour = 10 // 10AM
endHour = 18 // 6PM
console.log(isBetweenHours(currentHour, startHour, endHour)); // true: 18 is between 10 and <=18
```

Comment: OP failed to mention in his question that the range can span to next day, and that endhour is always after (in terms of a timeline) startHour. In which Jons answer below is correct. This code is incorrect because it doesnt check to see if endHour is before startHour, meaning its the next day. But of course Jons answer doesnt work if the end hour can be 24+ hours past startHour. So really OP is just not providing enough detail for anyone to confidently answer the question.